# How to add icon to my repository?

Tags: git, user-interface, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have found that Gitlab and SourceTree support icons for every repositories which make them more specific and easy to find at one glance.

How is this possible?

Comment: In GitLab, under the project settings there is a place to upload a "Project Avatar".

Comment: The feature has been broken on SourceTree for about 2 years: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-3096

Comment: I don't think so, cause I am using this feature right now! Read the last comment from the link you sent.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

We as a developer sometimes need a change to make our tools look different.

You can add a small(I prefer 96px x 96px) `logo.png` image file to the root of your repository.

[image: repository screenshot]

Which makes your project more specific and easy to find with [gitlab](http://gitlab.com) or [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) git client. Unfortunately github does not support this feature.

[image: gitlab screenshot]

It is very simple but it works!

[image: sourcetree screenshot]

**Update**: Thanks to your comments I have found another way within Gitlab repository settings:

[image: gitlab settings screenshot]

hope you enjoy this trick and make your tools more fun :)

Answer (score 37):

If you want to put an icon on your project in Gitlab, do the following instructions:

1. Go to your **project** then in left side click on **'Setting'**
2. Click on **'General'** then in **'General project'** section hit <kbd>**Expand**</kbd>
3. Then in project avatar section hit <kbd>**Choose file...**</kbd> your avatar icon file and
   upload it.
4. Finally hit <kbd>**Save changes**</kbd>

---

[**NOTE**]:

- <sub>Note that you should have the `Maintainer` permission on this project.</sub>
- <sub>Maximum size is 200KB</sub>

Comment: @VaggelisManousakis Yes, you should have the `Maintainer` permission on this project.