# Is it possible to change the icon of a gitlab group?

Tags: gitlab

I was wondering if it was possible to change the icon of a group on gitlab? Right now it's just the first letter of the project name, and I haven't been able to find anything online that says we can...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In GitLab, under the project settings there is a place to upload a "Project Avatar"
   [Image showing upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdCMg.png)
2. Or you can also use the method mentioned in the accepted answer in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049648/how-to-add-icon-to-my-repository)